# Is there a reason to know?

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, knowledge, reality, materialism

I am going to talk about the necessity of the reason to know by talking about the nature of spacetime, and therefore, of our nature. I'm not sure whether this is specific enough for StackExchange, but my question is, is the paragraph below sensible?

Here are my propositions:

1. It is not important to know the fake.
2. All that exists is the physical (physicalism).

There are two possibilities: either spacetime is real or fake. If it is fake, our "existence" is also fake. It is not important to know anything that is fake. So there is no need to know at all.

Otherwise, spacetime is real. If it is real, then so are we. Since all which exists is the physical, our minds must be a product of the physical. And due to the limit on all physicals, our minds are bounded on what we can store, as well as on what we can understand. Therefore, we can never know everything.

- What if we are our memories are bounded, but our ability to grasp is not?

It is impossible to occur because how will we ever know what we will never know? A contradiction therefore exists.

Comment: "A contradiction therefore exists." What contradiction ?

Comment: "Is there a reason to know?" Maybe it is part of human nature the *desire to know*. Maybe we a biological programmed to "investigate" our environment.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, the question above regarding a bounded memory yet an unlimited grasping ability.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I agree. We could be evolutionary beings, and one of the evolutionary parameters "fitness parameter" is the ability to investigate our environments. Does it support the argument though that we can never know because evolution carved our abilities to see reality (as Donald Hoffman [believes](https://www.npr.org/sections/13.7/2016/09/06/492779594/what-if-evolution-bred-reality-out-of-us))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is not important to know anything that is fake.

If my doctor's license is fake, I think it's important for me to know it. This statement isn't objectively true since "important" is subjective — it depends on what an individual values and considers important. Doesn't look like your conclusion holds.

> Therefore, we can never know everything.

This is correct.

> It is impossible to occur because how will we ever know what we will never know? A contradiction therefore exists.

If we will never know A, then there's no "how" to learn it. I don't see any contradiction here.

Just because you can't know *everything* doesn't mean that knowing *something* is useless. But there's no objective reason why you should care knowing about things. This has to do with your own values and preferences. I have a reason for studying engineering, you may or may not have one to study it too. A "reason for knowing" is subjective, it can't exist independently of an individual.

Comment: you're right that you'll need to know if your doctor's license is fake. However, I started out with the proposition that it is (objectively) unimportant to know the fake. If our entire existence is fake, it is obvious that your doctor's license is fake. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Importance presupposes a scale of values. A scale of values requires an individual (a subject). Something that's objectively the case doesn't requires an individual to be true — the property is contained in the object itself. Since importance cannot exist without an individual who thinks X is important, it cannot be the case that X is objectively important or unimportant. Proposition 1 cannot logically be held as objectively true.

Comment: I think you proved that "Nothing is objectively important or unimportant" which should falsify proposition 1. Do you, however, agree that there is no reason to know if everything is fake because there is not much point?

Comment: If that could be the case, yes... But I don't think it's a possible scenario. If we knew everything was fake then we would know at least one truth ("everything is fake"). By knowing this nor **everything** would be fake anymore. We would also know that we exist (cogito ergo sum) and that there's a possibility for error. If there's a possibility for error, there's more we can conclude. I think maybe you're talking about some physics I don't really understand and thus I'm unable to really imagine your scenario

Comment: @CaioCosta RE: "..here's no objective reason why you should care knowing about things".  It is an evolutionary advantage for me to know certain things.. like which berries are safe to eat. Could it be argued that I have evolved to care about those things to ensure the survival and reproduction of my genes?

Comment: @Michael Lautman yes, I agree with your argument. This is the reason why you care about things. It's part of your nature. It's objective. But just because you are the way you are, it doesn't mean you **should** or **ought** to be this way. My point is: there is no objective norm (at least none I'm aware of) which states you have a **duty** to care. This has to do with the is-ought problem.

Comment: @Damodar Dahal I'm not sure of "everything = fake" would mean. You can only consider something fake if you have a standard of non-fake. I don't think you can presuppose the existence of a universe in which everything is false, for to consider something false you'd need something which not false to compare. But if you don't have anything that's not fake to compare in that universe (since *everything* is "fake"), then what happens is that the universe itself becomes the standard of non-fake. (1/2)

Comment: @CaioCosta, point taken.  I am a scientist by training so I have a particular way of looking at things, and I am just starting to dig in to philosophy more rigorously.

Comment: @Damodar Dahal truth is the adequacy of our thoughts to the objects of our thoughts. If our thoughts were adequate to that universe in question, our thoughts would actually be true.  Again, I don't see how it could be logically possible for everything to be fake. I believe this is just impossible. (2/2)

Comment: @MichaelLautman that's great! I haven't read it yet, but I think Robert Audi's book on Epistemology probably worth the read if you're interested in the topic. Michael Huemer's works on epistemology are good reads too.

Comment: I started thinking that I understood it. Now I feel like I have not understood at all. Thank you CaioCosta and @MichaelLautman, I am free from a few doubts now.

Comment: Marking as answered because I can't think of this anymore without studying further.